# SIGABRT when accessing to just created UIViewController's view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have the next code:

```objective-c
- (void)func
{
    MyViewController *ctrl = [MyViewController new];
    [ctrl doSmth];
    [self presentViewController:ctrl animated:NO];
}

//------------

- (void)doSmth
{
    CGRect *rect = self.view.frame;
    // Do something with rect
    self.view.frame = rect;
}
```

Ok, I know, that when `-[UIViewController view]` is equal to `nil` then it's being created. And this code did work before my changes (only buttons and labels visibility, nothing extraordinary) and now it throws `SIGABRT` on `self.view`, it looks like it cannot be created. Suddenly. If I revert my changes, all work like a magic. And even if I won't call this function it'll crash on presenting and in Summary it'll show that `view = 0x00000000`.

I've got only one question: WAT?

Comment: Show your loadview/viewdidload method.

Comment: ctrl's view hasn't been loaded at the time you're calling doSmth. It's not loaded until its viewDidLoad is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the error.

After XCode's “refactoring” (renaming some `IBOutlets`) old outlets had been marked with the `!` sign but not removed and nothing XCode told me about it.

What I mean by `!`-s, is Interface Builder showing not valid outlets with an icon. Not valid outlet means that you have a connection between a view and a property / instance variable that does not exist. So when the NIB will be loaded in runtime, the application will crash, because there are no such property / instance variable.

[image: !-mark in IB]

So if you run in such error, you should either remove the outlet, or add the property / instance variable with the same name to class which you have linked the XIB to (usually a File's Owner).

Comment: Could you expand your answer a bit to describe where the `!`-s were, how you found them and how you got rid of them?  Thanks!